# Userform Checkboxes Code Error

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code I am attempting. I thought it was simple enough, but I fear my ignorance is my undoing. The code checks to see if a checkbox is true on sheet "A", then unhides Sheet "C" and puts a specific value into sheet "B". When I click the box, nothing happens.

```
Sub CheckBox164_Click()

    If CheckBox164.Value = True Then

        Active.Workbook.Unprotect

        Sheets("00 00 01").Visible = -1
        Worksheets("Summary").Cells(8, 2).Value = "GENERAL CONDITIONS"

        Active.Workbook.Protect True, True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line, step through it, and see what it does then.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Spelling error.